# How do Hindu scriptures define the physical appearance of Lord Rama?

Tags: ramayana, scripture, rama

Just wanted to know if there's any description of physical appearance of Lord Rama in the Hindu scriptures.

Answer (score 6):

These are some of the sanskrit shlokas or verses from [**Ayodhya kanda**](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga2/ayodhya_2_frame.htm) **" (अयोध्या कांड) , "Valmiki Ramayana** **(वाल्मिकी रामायण)"** **describing** **physical appearance of "Lord Rama(राम)**

> इच्छामो हि **महाबाहुं** रघुवीरं महाबलम् |
>   गजेन महता यान्तं रामं छत्रावृताननम् || २-२-२२
>
> All of us want to see Rama, **with long arms**, the hero with great
>   might born in the clan of Raghu , his face protected by a white
>   umbrella, moving on a great elephant."
>
> ---
>
> **तं चन्द्रमिव पुष्येण युक्तं** धर्मभृतां वरम् |
>   यौवराज्ये नियोक्तास्मि प्रीतः पुरुषपुङ्गवम् || २-२-१२
>
> "Joyfully, I shall appoint Rama, **who shines like the moon together
>   with Pushya star,** who is the best among the protectors of
>   righteousness and who is an excellent man, to the realm of prince."
>
> ---
>
> **सुभ्रूरायतताम्राक्ष्हस्साक्ष्हाद्विष्णुरिव** स्वयम् |
>   रामो लोकाभिरामोऽयं शौर्यवीर्यपराक्रमैः
>
> Rama, who enchants the world, **has beautiful eyebrows. He has red and
>   broad eyes.** He is absolutely like the God Vishnu himself in
>   strength, heroism and valour."
>
> ---
>
> तेषामायाचितं देव त्वत्प्रसादा त्समृद्ध्यताम् |
>    **राममिन्दीवरश्यामं** सर्वशत्रुनिबर्हणम् || २-२-५३
>   पश्यामो यौवराज्यस्थं तव राजोत्तमाऽअत्मजम् |
>
> "Oh best of kings, Dasaratha ! We shall see Rama adorned with princely
>   kingdom. Your son **Rama has the complexion of a black lotus flower**
>   and annihilates all his enemies. Let the wish of the people be
>   fulfilled by your grace."

We also find some shlokas describing **Physical appearance of Shree Rama in Puranas.**

Here what **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana Says...**

> गुर्वर्थे त्यक्तराज्यो व्यचरदनुवनं।**पद्मपद्भ्यां** प्रियाया: ॥४॥
>
> gurv-arthe tyakta-rājyo vyacarad anuvanaṁ padma-padbhyāṁ priyāyāḥ
>
> **Meaning**- To keep the promise of His father intact, Lord Rāmacandra immediately gave up the position of king and, accompanied by His wife,
>   mother Sītā, wandered from one forest to another on **His lotus feet,
>   which were so delicate** that they were unable to bear even the touch
>   of Sītā’s palms.[**SB 9.10.4**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/10/4)

Comment: @UdayKrishna - Yes , will look at them and will add these & other verses from various text's  later :)

Answer (score 5):

The following are the descriptions of the Lord as per Valmiki Ramayana(Sundarkand):

1)His hands are "ajanu lambita" meaning are so long that can be extended upto the knees.

2)He is broad shouldered.

3)His eyes are wide (comparable to lotus) and got a reddy tinge to it.

3)His neck is like a conch.

4)His voice is like the swash of ocean springs.

5)He is blue skinned like the color of the skies

6)He is well built and muscular and his walks reminds that of a lion.

7)His chest,fists and wrists are diamond strong.

8)His chest is convex,navel region is rich,belly muscles are slightly bulged.

9)His hair,penis and lines on foot soles are smooth.

10)His height is 12 feet.He has shining eyes,firm chin,even shape and lovely lips.

11)His canine teeth are strong.

Comment: Please cite sources.  Here is [Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/)

Comment: You can cite the source where Hanuman describes SriRama's physical appearance to Sita when they were interacting under the tree in asoka vana.

Comment: Per [this](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga35/sundarasans35.htm#Verse18) translation, Sri Rama's height was 96 inches = 8 ft.

Comment: @Rickross as stated in http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga35/sundarasans35.htm#Verse18 he is dark brown in complexion not blue skinned

Comment: @KishorePerla श्यामम् वर्णम् = [black or dark blue](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?beginning=0+&tinput=zyAma&trans=Translate). Sanskrit is preferable language for our scriptures.