# Was Rama eight feet tall?

Tags: rama

The popular Srivaishavite kalakshepam performer Dushyant Sridar said this in a recent Tamil lecture.

Is this supported by scripture?

This is not a duplicate, because in the other question, the answer is given as 12 feet and there is no direct citation.  A very knowledgeable lecturer said 8 feet and I want to know if Ramayana says the same thing.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10400/22556

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Hindu scriptures define the physical appearance of Lord Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/how-do-hindu-scriptures-define-the-physical-appearance-of-lord-rama)